Windows - How to load / start multiple sessions at startup (without logging in)?
At my home I have a computer running on Windows 11 Pro. I configured it so everyone in my family can use it (at the same time) on the local machine but also via Raspberry Pi RDP clients (using Remmina) for each user with their own sessions. It's working really great.
However, I have a "special" isolated session (mainly used through RDP) that I use as an ftp & web server, and I need this session to always be running and automatically loaded when the computer restarts (scheduled or power outage).
Precise AutoAdminLogon is already set in registry for a user session (my mom) used on the local machine.
How can I make the "server" session load in the background when the computer restarts?
Notes:

All users have passwords.
All sessions are local, not connected to MS account.
I don't want to run sessions in VMs because some users play games so it would kill performances.
In the server session, UI apps are loaded on session start (eg: Laragon).
The server session has no admin rights and just has some ports opened in firewall.

What I tried:

Install & run an automatic service running as server session user:

Running but not starting session.


Run scheduled task when Windows starts to run a program inside and as server session user:

Task launches but never ends and doesn't start the .exe nor session (even when "open session as task / service" is allowed for this user in the local group policy).



What I could do, but not clean solutions:

Setup AutoAdminLogon to server session and run a .bat script to lock it and connect with the password in clear text to my mom's account. (No way I'm doing this.)
On one of the RPIs, create an additional script that quickly open and close RDP to server session. (Not really fan of this either as only the computer is supposed to run 24/7.)

What behavior I want:
Simplest way to load the server session in background when Windows starts.
If needed I can code a C# app / service to programmatically do this, but I can't find documentation on how to do this.

Easiest way is to create services of the programs you need to start, and let SYSTEM start them.

I already thought about that but not really ideal for 2 reasons: First and obviously, UI apps like Laragon cannot be launched as service and even tho would very not convenient to manage / use. Second, letting SYSTEM (with full control rights) running for example apache as service could potentially lead to high risk in term of security, that's why i prefer using a custom session with very limited rights (btw I choose for example soft like Laragon because it don't rely on windows services, it's portable and run without admin rights)

Then use a dedicated machine for your servers, and setup auto start to that account. Don't mix a server and normal users if you can't use services so it runs in the background.

This what I was doing before, but to be honest I love the way it is powerful, centralized and working now. I'm in fact made and using services on the pc but under admin acc to monitor, send notifications. "Server" session is working perfectly once loaded, but i can't permit such rights on it. If i don't find any other solution, I'll keep the automate logging process via RDP from a Pi client script. Thanks for your advice anyway :)
